# Text editor in unix showing a higher record count than in Excel. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: unix

I was exporting a database table for 397 records using TeraData FastExport utility. The exported CSV file, when opened in Excel shows the correct record count as 398 (including a header). But in unix by using `wc -l` command the record count shows as 405 instead of 398. Even in Notepad++ the record count is 405.

I'm unable to figure out what might be causing this problem. Why would the record count of a csv file different between text editors and Excel?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In CSV you can have line breaks as part of a "value/cell", using quotes to clarify that's a value and not the start of a new row .

In this case,  the Excel would consider just a "cell"  and it won't increase the number of Excel rows,  while a text editor would recognize the line break and count it.